Scala plugin to get subclasses annotated with JsonCodec
I have a class which acts as a substitution for enum:
abstract class EnumClass[A](_v: A) { final def value: A = _v }

It has many subclasses in different packages like:
sealed abstract class EnumLevel1(value: String) extends EnumClass(value)

We have explicit JSON codecs for them. But some developers accidentally annotate these subclasses with @JsonCodec:
@JsonCodec
sealed abstract class EnumLevel1(value: String) extends EnumClass(value)

This means these classes are converted to JSON using @JsonCodec annotation instead of fetching explicit codecs for conversion.
So I wrote a plugin that could find the subclasses that are annotated with @JsonCodec:
import scala.tools.nsc.plugins.{Plugin, PluginComponent}
import scala.tools.nsc.{Global, Phase}

class EnumClassPlugin(val global: Global) extends Plugin {

  val name                              = "enum-class-plugin"
  val description                       = "Ensures no subclass of EnumClass is annotated with @JsonCodec"
  val components: List[PluginComponent] = List[PluginComponent](EnumClassComponent)

  private object EnumClassComponent extends PluginComponent {
    val global: EnumClassPlugin.this.global.type = EnumClassPlugin.this.global

    import global._

    override val runsAfter: List[String] = List("parser")
    override val phaseName               = "enumclassphase"

    def newPhase(prev: Phase): StdPhase = new StdPhase(prev) {
      override def name: String = phaseName

      def apply(unit: CompilationUnit): Unit = {
        unit.body.foreach {
          case classDef @ q"$mods class $tpeName[..$_] $_(...$_) extends { ..$_ } with ..$parents { $_ => ..$_ }" =>
            if (parents.exists(_.toString.contains("EnumClass"))) {
              val hasJsonCodec = mods.annotations.exists(_.toString.contains("JsonCodec"))
              if (hasJsonCodec) {
                global.reporter.error(
                  classDef.pos,
                  s"Class $tpeName extends EnumClass and should not be annotated with @JsonCodec"
                )
              }
            }
          case _ =>
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

This works for simple cases like the above. But in case the annotation is at the next level:
@JsonCodec
sealed abstract class EnumLevel2(value: String) extends EnumLevel1(value)

the above won't work.
I have already tried other compiler phases for this issue, but annotations have not been fetched by then, maybe because @JsonCodec is a macro and has been removed; I may be wrong about that. I also tried writing a macro for the same, but it had other issues. How can this work? Were macros the right way?
Versions used:

scala 2.13.10
circe 0.13.0

